# AddJwtBearer + AddAzureADBearer Not working together

Tags: c#, jwt

I am writing a authentication piece (.Net Core 2.1) where it can make use of either a JWT from a service provider or a token from AzureAD. I have written the following test to understand what is required , but it seems as if the first authentication provider is always hit when I test with Postman and send through a bearer token.

I have put a break point on both bearer providers events, if i call the values controller with the bearer token it hits the "first"  one even though i have specified to use the AuthenticationScheme of "second"

Startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication("first")
    .AddJwtBearer("first", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://123";
        options.TokenValidationParameters =
        new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidAudiences = new[] { "123" }
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                var accesToken = context.SecurityToken;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Principal;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
        })
    .AddAzureADBearer("second", 
        AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, 
        options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    // Added
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, 
        options =>
        {
        //Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        //options.Authority += "/v2.0";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[] { options.Audience, $"api://{options.Audience}" };

            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;

            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var accesToken = context.SecurityToken;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Principal;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

ValuesController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "second")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using policies to enable `AuthenticationSchemes`

We use something like this (didn't try running the code)

```
services
.AddPolicyScheme("first", "First policy selector", options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        return "first"
    };
})
.AddPolicyScheme("second", "Second policy selector", options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
    {
        return "second"
    };
})
.AddAuthentication("first")
    .AddJwtBearer("first", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://123";
        options.TokenValidationParameters =
        new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidAudiences = new[] { "123" }
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                var accesToken = context.SecurityToken;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Principal;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
        })
    .AddAzureADBearer("second", 
        AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, 
        options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    // Added
    services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, 
        options =>
        {
        //Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
        //options.Authority += "/v2.0";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[] { options.Audience, $"api://{options.Audience}" };

            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
            options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateLifetime = false;

            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    var accesToken = context.SecurityToken;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                {
                    var accessToken = context.Principal;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, I think the above issue is due to the following issue, where the default authentication scheme is always evaluated. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18940. . Pretty much defeats the purpose of using Authorize filter with the AuthenticationScheme.  Have applied a solution as you suggested with the PolicyScheme. Seems to be working.